# Calculating sentiment polarity using IMDb JSON reviews

Tags: python, json, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to calculate the average sentiment polarity using a JSON reviews with python. However, my codes are either looping infinitely to get all the polarity or I'll get an error "float object is not iterable" from using avg = sum(blob.polarity) / len(blob.polarity)

The JSON reviews data is a list of dicts like:

```
[
  {
    "date": "xx/xx/xxxx",
    "rate": "8.0",
    "Review text": "its such an awesome movie! the actions are intense!"
  },
  ...
]
```

My code:

```
response = requests.get("https://imdb.com/reviews/ironman.json") #not an actual URL 

if response:

   data = json.loads(response.text)
   content = ""

   for line in data:
       review = line["Review text"]
       content = content + review + " "
    
       blob = textblob.TextBlob(content)
       print("The average review polarity:", blob.polarity)

else:
   print("404 error.")
```

Output:

```
The average review polarity: 0.21027251552795012
The average review polarity: 0.20845378442639165
The average review polarity: 0.20358391721811314
……………… looping forever...
```

I am trying to get the average polarity on all the reviews. Basically, I only need to get one polarity output which is the average instead of multiple. I tried doing `sum(blob.polarity) / len(blob.polarity),` doing this will give me an error. I am stuck.

Comment: `if response.ok` not `if response`

Comment: Please show your attempt to do ` sum(blob.polarity) / len(blob.polarity)` so we can show you how to do it correctly (because that's the right way to calculate the mean value). There's also nothing in your code that would make it loop forever.

Comment: @ martineau - I just added avg = float(sum/blob.polarity) / float(len(blob.polarity) below blob = textblob. Then print("The average review polarity:",avg)

Comment: Try a debugger.  You'd be amazed at what you can learn using this basic tool.

Comment: @TomServo - It would be nice if my professor taught us how to use that tool on colab, I do not see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should more do something like:

```
response = requests.get("https://imdb.com/reviews/ironman.json")
if response.ok:
   reviews = json.loads(response.text)
   content = ' '.join([review["Review text"] for review in reviews])
   blob = textblob.TextBlob(content)
   print("The average review polarity:", blob.polarity)

else:
   print("404 error.")
```

I don't see the point of computing the polarity after each review text concatenation

Comment: Hi DevLounge, this was great! Though, we are required to calculate the average of all the reviews. Grateful for your help, thanks!